# javascript how to return object with key value

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures

```
const item = {date:'2021-07-22',
bfast: { 'name': 'spaghetti' ,'uid': 'pZjKW2rbOPOMYmdBoOzt' , 'done': false }, 
lunch: { 'name': 'spaghetti'  ,'uid': 'pZjKW2rbOPOMYmdBoOzt', 'done': false }, 
dinner: { 'name': 'spaghetti', 'uid': 'pZjKW2rbOPOMYmdBoOzt', 'done': false }
}

const formatRecipe = (uid ,time, item, uid, name) => {
 const = date.time
    if (time === 'bfast') {
      item.breakfast = {'name' : name, 'uid': uid, 'done': false}
    } else if (time === 'lunch') {
      item.lunch = {'name' : name, 'uid': uid, 'done': false}
    } else {
      item.dinner = {'name' : name, 'uid': uid, 'done': false}
    }
    return { day : [item] }
}

document.write(formatRecipe(item.date,'bfast', item, 'abc', 'spaghetti')['2021-07-22'])
```

hi everyone im stuck at some data structure issue.
as you can see i need to format the data as such so that it can be rendered by some library function. but as i have highlighted the “day” inside, the return statement wont refer to the parameter of the function, whereas i need the day as the key of the returned object. does anyone know a way to solve this?

Comment: This isn't even valid code is it? You have a duplicate parameter name and your const has no name and day is also undefined I guess. Maybe I am missing something but this looks quite weird to me.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I got your idea, but maybe this snippet will help you

```js
const item = {
  date: '2021-07-22',
  breakfast: {
    'name': 'spaghetti',
    'uid': 'pZjKW2rbOPOMYmdBoOzt',
    'done': false
  },
  lunch: {
    'name': 'spaghetti',
    'uid': 'pZjKW2rbOPOMYmdBoOzt',
    'done': false
  },
  dinner: {
    'name': 'spaghetti',
    'uid': 'pZjKW2rbOPOMYmdBoOzt',
    'done': false
  }
}

const formatRecipe = (time, item, uid, name, date) => {
  if (time === 'breakfast') {
    item.breakfast = {
      'name': name,
      'uid': uid,
      'done': false
    }
  } else if (time === 'lunch') {
    item.lunch = {
      'name': name,
      'uid': uid,
      'done': false
    }
  } else {
    item.dinner = {
      'name': name,
      'uid': uid,
      'done': false
    }
  }

  item.date = date.toISOString().split('T')[0];
}

formatRecipe("breakfast", item, 'abc', 'spaghetti', new Date());
console.log(item);
```